# angularjs putting <img> tags around image links in a post

Tags: angularjs, image

I am working on a website where my users can post things to a timeline. I have written the API's / views so the user can write and post things to a timeline. I load the string of their post from a database and display it using a ng-repeat on the timeline. If I have a fake post as such:

```
Hello! I went on a sweet camping trip yesterday, check out this photo! [img]http://example.image
```

How would one go about auto displaying that image?

I tried to find if this question had already been answered but had no such luck.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the syntax used in your posts? HTML? Markdown? Other?

Comment: Currently there is no syntax, I am trying to figure out what the best style would be for angular to handle easily.